# Question about Marginalizing Distributions from CMU 10-701, HWK3, Problem #3

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian-network

I have a question about a pseudocode write-up from an online course that I've been following. Currently I am going over the Bayes Nets section. Here are the links to the homework and it's solution key:

[http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~tom/10701_sp11/hw/3/hw3.pdf](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Etom/10701_sp11/hw/3/hw3.pdf)

[http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~tom/10701_sp11/hw/3/hw3_sol.pdf](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Etom/10701_sp11/hw/3/hw3_sol.pdf)

Specifically, question 3(a).

In my initial writeup, I had began my algorithm construction as this:

[image]

In the numerator, I converted this to a nested sum over $X_2,\dots, X_{(n-1)}$ of the joint probability distribution $P(X_1,\dots,X_n)$. Then we could use our Conditional Independence assumptions for Bayes Nets to break up this joint distribution:

[image]

In which case, our pseudocode would just be undoing this summation and dividing by our prior $P(X_1 = 1)$.

However this didn't seem to be completely correct. In the homework solution for 3(a), the author only sums over $X_{(n-1)}$. What rules of probability are being used here that allows us to ignore the other summations?

Comment: Doesn't that graph provides us that $P(X_n=x_n|X_{n-1}=x_{n-1},X_{n-2} =x_{n-2})=P(X_n=x_n|X_{n-1}=x_{n-1})$? Or more generally, once you condition the probability on the last period, the periods before it bring no new information. Because there is no arrow that connects periods with distance 2 or more..

Comment: That's correct, but I don't see the connection to where I'm at in the problem. After the joint distribution is made, I use that property in the second equation